# Отладка пока не достигнется значение

Tags: c#, visual-studio, инспекция-кода, отладка, resharper

Есть огромный код
Среди него нужно найти, когда (место в коде) значение одной из переменных-строк не станет равным "GV 7" из Visual Studio.

Т.к. переменных очень много - хотелось бы автоматизировать процесс.

Т.к. "GV 7" не хранится в открытом виде (полученна в ходе операций), то я не знаю

1) В какую переменную он придет

2) В каком месте кода

Вопрос: можно ли средствами VS 2019 и Resharper задать остановку отладки (BreakPoint) при получении этого значения?

P.S. Этот пример для упрощения понимания, на деле у меня все более сложнее...

Comment: В студии (или в решарпере, точно не помню) есть возможность найти все места, где идет запись в переменую. Зная все такие места, можно понаставить точек останова, у которых можно выставить условие на значение переменной.

Comment: Это при условии если переменных немного, а если их более 200.000?

Comment: @tym32167  я думал на тему регулярных выражений в переменном брейкпоинте, но, к сожалению, вроде, они все всё равно привязываются если не к переменной, то к  функции

Comment: Вы говорите о сферических конях в вакууме. Откуда у вас 200к переменных? Это массив? Вы можете найти место в коде, где этот массив меняется? Вы в курсе, что можете брейпоинты кодом ставить? ( что то типа `if (myarray.contains(mystring)) debug.break()`) зачем вам вообще искать эту переменую?

Comment: @tym32167 нет, это переменные, просто большой код